# Having issue displaying images from folder other than wwwroot folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Objective :**

We are planning to move images from Project folder to  C OR D drive(other folder from where the project is located.

Methodology I choosed

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Displaying-images-that-are-stored-outside-the-Website-Root-Folder.aspx

### IamgeDisplayPage.aspx

```
<asp:image ID="Image4" runat="server" ImageUrl ="TestPage.aspx?FileName=TestJPG.jpg"/>
```

TestPage.aspx.cs

```
try
{
    // Read the file and convert it to Byte Array
 string filePath = "C:\\images\\";
    string filename = Request.QueryString["FileName"];
    string contenttype = "image/" +
    Path.GetExtension(Request.QueryString["FileName"].Replace(".","");
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath + filename,
    FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
    br.Close();
    fs.Close();

    //Write the file to response Stream
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = contenttype;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
}
catch
{
}
```

**Issue**

I am getting the image ffrom local machine and some buttons have to enabled after getting the image .This is all working fine in local machine.But in web server i am able to get the image but nothing is happening after that . The buttons are not being displyed and the values selected from the dropdowns before getting the image is also gone.

Trying to figure whats the difference between local server/casini and IIS when using the above methodology?Why is it is failing in webserver?

Comment: Be aware that your current implementation is vulnerable. Hackers could use URLS like `TestPage.aspx?FileName=..\some\path\to\sensitive\file.doc` to get files from the server's hard drive

Answer (score 1):

IIS is running under its own credentials. Probably it has no access to your `c:\images` folder. Try granting read access to `Everyone` on that folder.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to grant Read permission on your c:\images folder for the IIS users. Depending on your server OS, look for one of the following users:

NETWORKSERVICE

IIS_IUSRS

As torvin has pointed out, your current code is vulnerable. So as long as you're comfortable that all files in your images folder are accessible by anyone who can view TestPage.aspx, then you're good.

Comment: Not only in the `images` folder. Using `..` a hacker can access any file on the disk.